# CSS Bootstrap AutoFocus CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to render a grid of large buttons using bootstrap with React.

I have css for hover and focus effects. When user loads the screen, I want one of the buttons loaded as focused. I tried putting autofocus in the div. It does the job, however there is a weird formatting issue. Some thin white border on top of my regular borders renders. I couldn't figure out the exact issue and how not to display this white thin border when a user loads the screen.

My html:

```
     <div className='container '>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-6 about-btn-box ' >
          <button
            className='p-3 flexbox' autoFocus>
            <h4 > AAA  </h4>
            <p>
             sdadsasd  dasdsa dadasd asddaads dasdasdas
            </p>
          </button>
        ....
```

My CSS file:

```
    .about-btn-box {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding-bottom: 100px !important;
  color: whitesmoke !important;
  border-top:10px solid transparent!important ;
  border-left:10px solid transparent!important ;
  border: transparent !important;

}

.flexbox{
  border: transparent !important;
    display:flex;
  top: 5px;
    justify-content:top;
    align-items: left;
    flex-flow: column;
}
.about-btn-box button {
  background-color:transparent  !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:none;
  height: 170px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border-top:10px solid transparent!important ;
  border-left:10px solid transparent!important ;

  margin-bottom: 20px !important;

}


.about-btn-box h4 {
  color: whitesmoke;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  font-family: "Montserrat" !important;
  font-size: 18pt !important;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.about-btn-box p {
  align-items:baseline;

  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  text-align: left;
  align-items : left;
  font-size: 12.5pt !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  font-family: "Montserrat" !important;
  text-shadow: none;

}

.about-btn-box button:focus {
  border-left:10px solid red!important ;
  border-top:10px solid red!important ;

  background-color: rgb(26, 26, 36) !important;

}

.about-btn-box button:active {
  border-left:10px solid red!important ;
  border-top:10px solid red!important ;

  background-color: rgb(10, 11, 22) !important;

}

.about-btn-box button:hover {
  border-top:10px solid red!important ;

  border-left:10px solid red!important ;
  transition: all 200ms linear !important;


}
```

[image: This is how it looks like when I enable autofocus:]

I want to get rid of the white outer borders but want the button loaded with autofocus.

Below is how i want it to look like when it loads with autoFocus:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Add CSS `outline: none !important;` on `.about-btn-box button` selector :-

```
.about-btn-box button{outline: none !important;}
```